# Border Radius Prevent Clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [this color wheel](https://github.com/bgrins/colorwheel-1k), and I want to make it that when you click outside the canvas, when you click the border radius, nothing should happen.

I have to prevent 2 things from happening:

- I have to prevent the cursor from becoming a pointer.
- I have to prevent the color and the `dragger` to not move and change.
  Or I could just not call `redraw()`.

Here's what I tried doing: In the `redraw()` function, at the `if statement` of `d > radiusSquared` (line 97), I consoled a random string to know when the `if statement` gets called, so I can insert the prevention's there.

The problem with doing that, is if you start dragging the dragger in the canvas, then drag out of the canvas, it still consoles the string. (I hope this is clear. If you have a better way of expressing my point, please edit the question.)

How can I prevent changes from happening if the cursor is out of the border radius of the canvas, whether the dragging started within the canvas, or out of the canvas?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var b = document.body;
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
var a = c.getContext('2d');
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
document.body.clientWidth; // fix bug in webkit: http://qfox.nl/weblog/218

var colorWheelDiv = document.createElement('div');
var dragger = document.createElement('div');
dragger.id = 'dragger';

var otherDiv = document.createElement('div');
colorWheelDiv.appendChild(c);
colorWheelDiv.appendChild(dragger);
colorWheelDiv.style.position = 'relative';

wrapper.appendChild(otherDiv);
wrapper.appendChild(colorWheelDiv);

(function() {

  // Declare constants and variables to help with minification
  // Some of these are inlined (with comments to the side with the actual equation)
  var doc = document;
  doc.c = doc.createElement;
  b.a = b.appendChild;

  var width = c.width = c.height = 400,
    label = b.a(doc.c("p")),
    input = b.a(doc.c("input")),
    imageData = a.createImageData(width, width),
    pixels = imageData.data,
    oneHundred = input.value = input.max = 100,
    circleOffset = 0,
    diameter = width - circleOffset * 2,
    radius = diameter / 2,
    radiusPlusOffset = radius + circleOffset,
    radiusSquared = radius * radius,
    two55 = 255,
    currentY = oneHundred,
    currentX = -currentY,
    wheelPixel = circleOffset * 4 * width + circleOffset * 4;

  // Math helpers
  var math = Math,
    PI = math.PI,
    PI2 = PI * 2,
    sqrt = math.sqrt,
    atan2 = math.atan2;

  // Setup DOM properties
  b.style.textAlign = "center";
  label.style.font = "2em courier";
  input.type = "range";

  // Load color wheel data into memory.
  for (y = input.min = 0; y < width; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      var rx = x - radius,
        ry = y - radius,
        d = rx * rx + ry * ry,
        rgb = hsvToRgb(
          (atan2(ry, rx) + PI) / PI2, // Hue
          sqrt(d) / radius, // Saturation
          1 // Value
        );

      // Print current color, but hide if outside the area of the circle
      pixels[wheelPixel++] = rgb[0];
      pixels[wheelPixel++] = rgb[1];
      pixels[wheelPixel++] = rgb[2];
      pixels[wheelPixel++] = d > radiusSquared ? 0 : two55;
    }
  }

  // Bind Event Handlers
  input.onchange = redraw;
  dragger.onmousedown = c.onmousedown = doc.onmouseup = function(e) {
    // Unbind mousemove if this is a mouseup event, or bind mousemove if this a mousedown event
    doc.onmousemove = /p/.test(e.type) ? 0 : (redraw(e), redraw);
  }

  // Handle manual calls + mousemove event handler + input change event handler all in one place.
  function redraw(e) {

    // Only process an actual change if it is triggered by the mousemove or mousedown event.
    // Otherwise e.pageX will be undefined, which will cause the result to be NaN, so it will fallback to the current value
    currentX = e.pageX - $(c).offset().left - radiusPlusOffset || currentX;
    currentY = e.pageY - $(c).offset().top - radiusPlusOffset || currentY;

    // Scope these locally so the compiler will minify the names.  Will manually remove the 'var' keyword in the minified version.
    var theta = atan2(currentY, currentX),
      d = currentX * currentX + currentY * currentY;

    // If the x/y is not in the circle, find angle between center and mouse point:
    //   Draw a line at that angle from center with the distance of radius
    //   Use that point on the circumference as the draggable location
    if (d > radiusSquared) {
      console.log('outside');
      currentX = radius * math.cos(theta);
      currentY = radius * math.sin(theta);
      theta = atan2(currentY, currentX);
      d = currentX * currentX + currentY * currentY;
    }

    label.textContent = b.style.background = hsvToRgb(
      (theta + PI) / PI2, // Current hue (how many degrees along the circle)
      sqrt(d) / radius, // Current saturation (how close to the middle)
      input.value / oneHundred // Current value (input type="range" slider value)
    )[3];

    // Reset to color wheel and draw a spot on the current location. 
    a.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    // Draw the current spot.
    // I have tried a rectangle, circle, and heart shape.
    /*
    // Rectangle:
    a.fillStyle = '#000';
    a.fillRect(currentX+radiusPlusOffset,currentY+radiusPlusOffset, 6, 6);
    */
    /*
    // Circle:
    a.beginPath();  
    a.strokeStyle = '#000';
    a.arc(~~currentX+radiusPlusOffset,~~currentY+radiusPlusOffset, 4, 0, PI2);
    a.stroke();
    */

    // Heart:
    /*a.font = "1em arial";
    a.fillText("♥", currentX + radiusPlusOffset - 4, currentY + radiusPlusOffset + 4);*/

    dragger.style.left = (~~currentX + radiusPlusOffset) + 'px';
    dragger.style.top = (~~currentY + radiusPlusOffset) + 'px';

  }

  // Created a shorter version of the HSV to RGB conversion function in TinyColor
  // https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor/blob/master/tinycolor.js
  function hsvToRgb(h, s, v) {
    h *= 6;
    var i = ~~h,
      f = h - i,
      p = v * (1 - s),
      q = v * (1 - f * s),
      t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s),
      mod = i % 6,
      r = [v, q, p, p, t, v][mod] * two55,
      g = [t, v, v, q, p, p][mod] * two55,
      b = [p, p, t, v, v, q][mod] * two55;

    return [r, g, b, "rgb(" + ~~r + "," + ~~g + "," + ~~b + ")"];
  }

  // Kick everything off
  redraw(0);

  /*
  // Just an idea I had to kick everything off with some changing colors…
  // Probably no way to squeeze this into 1k, but it could probably be a lot smaller than this:
  currentX = currentY = 1;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
      currentX--;
      currentY*=1.05;
      redraw(0)
  }, 7);
    
  setTimeout(function() {
      clearInterval(interval)
  }, 700)
  */

})();
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#dragger {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='wrapper'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the colour and dragger from changing:

```
if (d > radiusSquared) {
  currentX = radius * math.cos(theta);
  currentY = radius * math.sin(theta);
  theta = atan2(currentY, currentX);
  d = currentX * currentX + currentY * currentY;
}else{
  label.textContent = b.style.background = hsvToRgb(
    (theta + PI) / PI2,
    sqrt(d) / radius,
    input.value / oneHundred 
  )[3];
  a.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  dragger.style.left = (~~currentX + radiusPlusOffset) + 'px';
  dragger.style.top = (~~currentY + radiusPlusOffset) + 'px';
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jo1a5ggr/1/)

As for the pointer, one option is to catch mouseover events on the canvas, and manually set the pointer according to position.

Comment: Thanks! The code you sent works! I tried the thing you said about catching the mouseover events, and it doesn't work as it should. Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/gedzq2mf/

Comment: Glad I could help! I changed `onmouseover` to `onmousemove` and it seems to work correctly https://jsfiddle.net/gedzq2mf/1/

Comment: Thanks! Also, is there a way to use JavaScript only? I used `offset()` from JQuery. Can I use something from Javascript that's the same as `offset()`?

Comment: Sure, you can check out [JQuery's implementation of offset()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/offset.js). However I would use JQuery's offset() myself. And please set this question as answered if you feel it has been answered!

Comment: Just realized, there is an undesirable behavior. If you click and drag in the canvas, then you drag out of the canvas, the draggers position, and the color doesn't change. How can I **not** prevent the regular behavior when the drag/click starts in the canvas?

Comment: I think I've got it: https://jsfiddle.net/gedzq2mf/3/   If not, you're gonna have to be more specific.

Comment: That partially works. If you click and drag outside the border radius, the color and dragger still updates.

Comment: So it turns out the value of d when outside of the circle is 3999.9999, no matter how far out. So it's always smaller then 4000, which always updates the colour and dragger. This should do it: https://jsfiddle.net/gedzq2mf/4/

Comment: If you click in the canvas, then click at the top left, outside the border radius, the color changes. (I hope that's clear. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99473/discussion-between-arcanecraeda-and-jessica).

Comment: I tried doing the following on line 97 `c.onmousemove = c.mousedown = function (e) {`, and it still didn't work as expected

Comment: Alright, I fixed it. I moved line 80, which was calling redraw() on mousedown, into the if block, which checks if the mousedown event is inside the wheel. https://jsfiddle.net/gedzq2mf/5/